# File could not be found when importing code snippet in VuePress

Tags: vuepress

According to VuePress's [documentation](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/markdown.html#import-code-snippets)

I would like to import code snippet into the Markdown file, but the documentation is not quite clear how can I work with the file path.

*Path*

```
|-package.json
+-src
|    |-readme.md
|    +-snippets
|    |    |-file.js
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vuepress dev src"
  }
}
```

*src/readme.md*

```
<<< @/snippets/file.js

<<< @/src/snippets/file.js
```

*Output*

```
Not found: d
```

I have tried many different ways to import code snippet but it's still not working.

Comment: Does `src/snippets/file.js` work?

Comment: It's work, I was led on by the documentation, thanks :)